# Re-scheduling Alarms after device reboot

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` which is supposed to re-schedule AlarmManager's Alarms after device reboots. After reboot `onReceive()` method is triggered (I can see `Log.v` output in the logcat) but the rest of the code doesn't re-schedule any alarms. Maybe there is something wrong with it but logcat shows only this:

logcat:

```
11-25 15:51:17.680    2192-2212/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc com.example.app for broadcast com.example.app/.BReceiver: pid=3668 uid=10080 gids={50080, 3003, 1015, 1028}
11-25 15:51:25.570    2192-2203/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ No longer want com.example.app (pid 3668): empty #17
```

Receiver:

```
public class BReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.v("BOOT_COMPLETED", "RECEIVED"); // this is logged

    DBScheduledRecords dbrec = new DBScheduledRecords(context);
    Cursor cur = dbrec.selectAllRecords();
    cur.moveToFirst();

    while(cur.moveToNext()) {
        int duration = cur.getInt(5);
        String link = cur.getString(1);
        int randomInt = cur.getInt(6);
        Long start = cur.getLong(8);

        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();   // current instance

        if (today.getTimeInMillis() > start) {
            start = start + (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7);
        }


        long lDuration = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(duration * 60000));
        Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, WakefulReceiver.class);

        //  startIntent.setAction("ALARM");
        startIntent.putExtra("httpAddress", link);
        startIntent.putExtra("millis", lDuration);
        startIntent.putExtra("startInMillis", start);
        startIntent.putExtra("randomInt", randomInt);


        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, randomInt, startIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, start, pendingIntent);


    }

}
}
```

Comment: Do not do file I/O on the main application thread. I'd move all that logic into an `IntentService`, started by `onReceive()`. Beyond that, add logging to your loop.

Comment: As i can see you are setting your alarm inside while loop.Have you made sure program counter does go inside while loop?

Comment: You do not need a loop. Just schedule the earliest alarm then when the alarm fires, schedule the next one. There is no need to have multiple alarms set as it will always be the earliest one that will fire first.

Comment: @Kuffs mind that every alarm has different extras inside its intent.

Comment: That doesn't matter. There is still always going to be only one alarm that will be the "next" one. Whenever you set the next one up, you can give it whatever extras it needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it revealed there was a few problems here, but the reason of having "no effect" in the logcat was caused by: `while(cur.moveToNext())` plus the fact I had only one row in my database (cursor poitner was already behind only row in the DB after calling `moveToNext()`). Now I'm using:

```
while(cur.getCount() > cur.getPosition()) {
  //
  cur.moveToNext();
}
```

In the meantime (while I was thinking of the reason of such behavior) I moved the code to the IntentService as @CommonsWare suggested.

Thanks for your comments. This was really helpful.